# Перевести с Python на Haskell алгоритм Форда Фалкерсона

Tags: haskell

```
redfu :: Integer->[[[Integer]]]->Integer
redfu s= [[[s,s,s]]]
redfu x=x
--red_1 s= if s/=end then red_2 x end


set_graph :: Integer->Integer
set_graph x = if x==(-1) then redfu a v else redfu a v where a=10
                                                             v=[[[0,0,1], [20,0,1], [30,0,1], [10,0,1], [0,0,1]],[[20,0,-1], [0,0,1], [40,0,1], [0,0,1], [30,0,1]],[[30,0,-1], [40,0,-1], [0,0,1], [10,0,1], [20,0,1]],[[10,0,-1], [0,0,1], [10,0,-1], [0,0,1], [20,0,1]],[[0,0,1], [30,0,-1], [20,0,-1], [20,0,-1], [0,0,1]]]
                                                             n = length v
                                                             init1 = 0
                                                             ut2=init1
                                                             end = 4
                                                             s3 = [unity(end,-1)(init1)]
```

В целом, получается, но не могу никак передать тройной список в функцию. Что я делаю не так? Вот что пока сделано. В идеале я хотел бы вывести все аргументы, что в блоке `where` в функции `redfu`. Как я могу выполнить это?

Comment: Что я делаю не так? И как передать список v?

Comment: 1. Сигнатура функции `redfu` и ее вызов говорят, что функция от двух аргументов, но реализация обрабатывает только один... Если я ничего не путаю :)  2. После редактирования вопроса код стал выглядеть весьма странно.  В Haskell пробелы и отступы - часть синтаксиса, так что теперь от строчки `v=[[[...` и до конца кода все это вывалилось из определения  `set_graf` 3. Смысл последних пяти строчек до меня вообще не дошел

Comment: Смотрите я могу сделать вам скиншот

Comment: Поправил. Теперь вам должно быть понятно что я именно хочу выполнить. Смотрите, у меня есть несколько параметров, но я не могу вдуплить как передать тройной список. 
Последние 5 строчек - это тоже будущие параметры. Просто я их не вызываю. Для меня сейчас проблема это передать в список функцию redfu

Comment: Не обязательно, мне достаточно Вашего начального варианта кода. У Вас, кстати, этот код вообще компилируется?

Comment: Нет......причём если я передаю параметр a, то всё нормально. В противном случае - беда.
Давайте наверное поясню суть истории. Мне нужно изначально перевести фалкерсона с питона на хаскел. Вот и пишу сюда. Я хорошо знаю Питон. Очень даже.
В коде на Python есть 2 цикла While.  Вот конструкция if - это мои попытки сделать что-то похожее на while, только на хаскелл.

Comment: Кстати, я не совсем верно поправил Ваш код, исправьте, пожалуйста, сами. Все определения в `where` должны начинаться с одной позиции под `a=10` и ни одним символом левее

Comment: И вот не знаю что и делать.......весь мозг сломал ко всем чертям......не передаётся он.

Comment: Увы, название "Фалкерсон" мне ни о чем не говорит. По коду. 1) В хаскеле нет циклов. 2. Начните с функции `redfu` Сейчас она у Вас выглядит очень странно, и непонятно, что там имелось в виду

Comment: Это алгоритм Форда Фалкерсона.

Comment: Увы, я его не знаю, и даже не знаю - из какой это области. Но! `redfu :: Integer->[[[Integer]]]->Integer` - здесь Вы говорите, что функция принимает два аргумента: целое число, и список целых с тремя уровнями вложения (список списков списков целых), а возвращает - целое число.  А вот здесь: `redfu s= [[[s,s,s]]]` - функция применяется  к одному аргументу (судя по сигнатуре - целому числу) и пытается вернуть вложенный список из трех числе, равных аргументу, что не соответствует сигнатуре. Далее: `redfu x=x` получаем целый аргумент и его возвращаем.

Comment: Применение `redfu` соответствует сигнатуре: `redfu a v `, но ее реализация в корне не верна.  И из написанного я не могу даже предположить, что имелось в виду. Так же, как не понимаю, что такое вот это: `n = length v
                                                             init1 = 0
                                                             ut2=init1
                                                             end = 4
                                                             s3 = [unity(end,-1)(init1)]`

Comment: Единственное, что я Вам могу сейчас посоветовать: разберитесь сначала с синтаксисом языка: как пишутся функции, как используются отступы и т.д. Потому что сейчас ощущение, что Вы совершенно не понимаете, что пишете. Извините за резкость, если что.

Comment: Так оно и есть) Надо читать. и вникать